Hovermap Data Pre -processing
The cloudcompare can not make the map without a single digit value which has been collected by the hovermap. How to preprocess that value. It seems very important digit to make the 3D map properly.enter image description here
I am trying to pre process the data that collected by hovermap. Inside the csv file, it generate one digit number along with thousands of point cloud number which maybe carries a big information of the 3D map that i am not aware of. Whenever I try to delete this value, it does not show me the full map properly. what is this data and how can process this value to use this on cloudcompare without any error. Is there any process to convert this number into axis values to make the 3D map? Please open the image to understand the dataset and type.
